# Hadoop NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Does anyone have any idea why something that used to work before all of a sudden started giving this error? please help

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters.findCounter(Ljava/lang/Enum;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter;
at edu.umn.cs.spatialHadoop.operations.Sampler.sampleMapReduceWithRatio(Sampler.java:214)
at edu.umn.cs.spatialHadoop.operations.Sampler.sample(Sampler.java:543)
at edu.umn.cs.spatialHadoop.operations.Repartition.packInRectangles(Repartition.java:494)
at edu.umn.cs.spatialHadoop.operations.Repartition.packInRectangles(Repartition.java:463)
at edu.umn.cs.spatialHadoop.operations.Repartition.repartitionLocal(Repartition.java:590)
```

This has been working earlier but suddenly started giving this error. I am using hadoop version 1.2.1

Comment: You probably updated/downgraded something such that there is now a method missing.

Comment: What has been working before? Show the code that causes the error.

Comment: @Stibu there is no need for code snippets, look at the error, everything could have caused it.

Comment: everything that has been in the folder is still there. I never upgraded or downgraded anything.

Answer (score 0):

from `org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter` I guess that the `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar` is missing

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` class is included in `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar`. You must have downgraded it somehow.

If you are using a build tool (maven, gradle...), check your dependencies and make sure they haven't changed. In case of doubt, just apply the latest version.

Else, go to your `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar` and either check if the method is inside or just get a newer version to replace it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of latest compiled class and dependent jar available in the application are of different version. For example: Let Class A compiled with dependent jar X in place then later same Class A compiled in different environment withe dependent jar X1 which consist new method called Y in that. now the class will be compiled because new method Y is available in jar X1 when the same Class A is used in the environment with jar X in place then it leads to the NoSuchMethod Exception when trying to load the class in the class memory. Classloader does the verification of the dependent classes before loading the class in the class memory before invoking real exceution.

Answer (score 0):

Everything were available all jar files and all. After an exhausting work thinking of whats wrong, i decided to reload everything afresh (i.e reload the hadoop files). Thanks to you guys for helping :)